# Populate a class from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, performance, reflection

I have a dictionary collection of more than 100 fields and values. Is there a way to populate a gigantic class with a 100 fields using this collection?

The key in this dictionary corresponds to the property name of my class and the value would be the Value of the Property for the class.

```
Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myDictionary.Add("MyProperty1", "Hello World");
myDictionary.Add("MyProperty2", DateTime.Now);
myDictionary.Add("MyProperty3", true);
```

Populates the properties of the following class.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string MyProperty1 {get;set;}
   public DateTime MyProperty2 {get;set;}
   public bool MyProperty3 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: do you mean populate the class? or generate the class? if it is the former, just use reflection.

Comment: Is there a reason why your class has hundreds of properties rather than, say, a collection class of an interface or type that can describe each piece of data?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) to get a list of properties for a given type and use [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx) to set a specific value for a given property:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
...
foreach (var pi in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
{
     object value;
     if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(pi.Name, out value)
     {
          pi.SetValue(myObj, value);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MyClass yourinstance...

foreach (var KVP in myDictionary)
{
    yourinstance.GetType().GetProperty ( KVP.Key ).GetSetMethod().Invoke ( yourinstance, new object[] { KVP.Value } );
}
```